# I have a problem making an iframe responsive and setting its height in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

```
<div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; width:100%; height:auto;" class="responsiveIframeWrapper"><iframe id="responsiveIframe4" class="responsiveIframePatrickP" data-break-points="[]" data-width-iframe="800" data-height-iframe="" scrolling="no" src="link"></iframe></div>
```

This is the code of the iframe which I want to implement in a wordpress page. Out of some reason it does not work whatever the code I put there in order to set the height of the container.[This is the way it looks now and i want to be able to modify its height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftebV.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a famous "padding hack" to make an element like an iframe responsive, but nowadays it's much easier to use the CSS `aspect-ratio` property.

```html
<iframe style="aspect-ratio: 16/9; width:100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8OtW8pKWYyk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
</iframe>
```

The equivalent "padding hack" method looks something like this:

```html
<div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; overflow: hidden;">
    <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8OtW8pKWYyk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Are your iframes cross-origin? That is, do they point to web sites other than yours? This matters because it's sometimes necessary for the doc in the iframe to post a message about its height to the outr page.  See [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iframe-resizer). Please edit your question to explain.

Comment: I think you meant this comment for the OP.

Comment: You're right, I did mean it for the OP,

Comment: Yes it is cross-origin. The point of the app is to bring from another server a login/register app made in VUE. Once you click register there are 5 steps that you need to complete in order to be registered as an user. Going threw each steps modifies the height and width of the page. This means that the iframe size has to change based on its contents. Also the problem may be that it has to be implemented in a wordpress page. I hope I didnt cause any misunderstandings. Thank you for the first solution so far!